# Sharkovskii`s theorem and a period three orbit of the logistic map at e.g. $r=3.83$

Tags: chaos-theory, fixed-points

Let $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ be continuous with a period three orbit.
We know with Sharkovskii`s theorem that f owns period orbits of any natural number.

If we take a look to the bifurcation-diagram of the logistic map, we can find a period three orbit for e.g. $r=3.83$, see [bifurcation-diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyHht.jpg) and [period three orbit of the bifurcation-diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2epOJ.jpg).

To give an example: Let $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$, $x\to 3.83x(1-x)$ and $g(x):=f(f(f(x)))$ the triple composition of f. The bifurcation-diagram of the logistic map shows a period three orbit at $r=3.83$, so g has three fixed points of period three and f has three accumulation points. With Sharkovskii`s theorem I'd expect orbits of all periods at this given $r=3.83$. The bifurcation-diagram only shows three stable fixed-points. Wikipedia says: " In fact, there must be cycles of all periods there, but they are not stable and therefore not visible on the computer-generated picture." But if I plot the graph of g, we only find a finite number of fixed points (both stable and unstable) but not infinite, see [graph of $g$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9q3e.jpg).

So how can I explain, that this doesn't  contradicts with Sharkovskii`s theorem? How is it possible, that g has a infinite number of fixed points if it only has a finite number of intersections with the bisecting line, wich are fixed points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The periodic orbits of higher period (say $n>3$) correspond to fixpoints of the $n$-fold iterated map $f^{(n)} = f \circ f \circ \dots \circ f$, not of the $3$-fold iterated map $g = f^{(3)} = f \circ f \circ f$. So you should look for them in the graphs of $f^{(4)}$, $f^{(5)}$, $f^{(6)}$, etc. – not in the graph for $g$.

(As you say, obviously $g$ doesn't have infinitely many fixpoints. But nobody is claiming that it should! "There must be cycles of all periods" means something completely different.)

Comment: So in the case $r=3.83$ we can find for any natural number $m$ fixpoints of period $m$, so that $f^m(x)=x$. In this case these fixpoints are unstable fixpoints of f but stable fixpoints of $f^3$. Can one say, that for $r=3,83$ $f^m$ with $m>3$ has multiple fixpoints but no stable fixpoints. Otherwise one could see more fixpoints in the bifurcation-diagram.

But how can one proof, that the bifurcation-diagramm of the logistic map contains period orbits of any natural period? I thought, that this was the result of Sharkovskii`s theorem, but this theorem fixes the $r$ of the bifurcation-diagram

Comment: The ones that are stable for $m=3$ will also give rist to stable fixpoints for $m=6,9,\ldots$, but except for that I think that they must be unstable (for the reason that you gave, and because ).